# why setsid could not exit from shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, setsid

```
$ cat test1.sh
#!/bin/bash

setsid sleep 100
```

'test1.sh' shell script will *not* exit at once.

```
$ cat test2.sh
#!/bin/bash

setsid sleep 100 &
```

'test2.sh' shell script will exit at once.

Could anyone explain for me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `&` puts the command into background which causes the latter to exit.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with the `setsid` command.

Comment: 'setsid' will deamonize a process, so I expect that the script goes on executing after 'setsid sleep 100' rather than wait 100 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

*The question is probably a duplicate of [this even older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677306/linux-command-setsid), and the answer over there is quite useful. Perhaps these should be merged.*

I was also surprised by this behaviour of `setsid`. So I checked the man page:

```
DESCRIPTION
       setsid runs a program in a new session. The command calls fork(2) if already a
       process group leader. Otherwise, it executes a program in the current process.
       This default behavior is possible to override by the --fork option.
```

Some jargon to understand here. Let's check the [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/nframe.html) definitions list (chapter 3).

A session is:

> A collection of process groups established for job control purposes. Each process group is a member of a session. A process is considered to be a member of the session of which its process group is a member. A newly created process joins the session of its creator. A process can alter its session membership; see setsid(). There can be multiple process groups in the same session.

The `fork()` call creates a new process by copying the current process. More info [in this post](https://percona.community/blog/2021/01/04/fork-exec-wait-and-exit/).

A process group leader is:

> A process whose process ID is the same as its process group ID.

So, `setsid` will only create a new process if it is executed as a process group leader. This is always the case when running a command directly in the shell, so that the job queue can be constructed as a list of process groups. However, when run as part of a script, the group leader is the new shell process used to run the script.

Luckily, we have the `--fork` option to force creation of a new process. For example, the shell script:

```
#!/bin/env bash
setsid --fork sleep 5
```

will exit without waiting for `sleep` to finish, and the `sleep` command will continue even if you close the shell from which the script was run. As far as I am aware, **`setsid --fork` is the only way to properly ensure that a command is run as a detached process**.

Other resources:

- [Forum discussion about setsid](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/setsid-and-command-line-piping-in-bash-638216/)
- [Source code for setsid](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/plain/sys-utils/setsid.c?id=HEAD)
- [Blog post explaining the difference compared to nohup](https://hauweele.net/%7Egawen/blog/?tag=setsid)

Comment: Excellent answer, but as of 20230721 setsid is not part of posix shell utilities: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html. `#!/usr/bin/env bash` looks better to me, because posix neither mandates where to install utilities.

Answer (score 0):

Your first script waits for `setsid sleep 100` to be finished and then returns (in other words it will return after sleep finishes, 100 seconds here), but the 2nd script don't waits for the command to finish, cause `&` puts the command in background and returns immediately. To quote `man bash`:

```
If  a  command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the
command in the background in a subshell. The shell does not wait for the command
to finish, and the return status is 0.
```

Also note that `&` is a control operator and it has higher precedence. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know the usage of '&' in shell script. If 'setsid' is removed, your answer is very good. But 'setsid' is used here. Can you explain it to me from the 'setsid' point?